# Is possible to get a constant value declared in a database package? (SQL or Java)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have some Packages in a Oracle database. They contain stored procedures, functions and constants. I can call functions, in Java, using a Java CallableStatement. Also, I could execute a SQL statement as "select package1.function1(value1) from dual;". But I can't find how to get the value of a constant declared in the package, in Java.

For example:

```
PACKAGE Package1 AS
    A_CONSTANT CONSTANT VARCHAR2 := 'Constant value';
END Package1;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using an anonymous PL/SQL block in a `CallableStatement`:

```
String constantValue;

CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("BEGIN ? := Package1.A_CONSTANT; END;");
try {
    statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    statement.execute();
    constantValue = statement.getString(1);
} finally {
    statement.close();
}
```

Comment: +1, much better answer than one from DCookie IF constant is declared in the interface not in the body of package.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this. You'll need a "getter" function to return the value of a public variable or constant defined in a pacakge:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Package1 IS
    A_CONSTANT CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'Constant value a';
    B_CONSTANT CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'Constant value b';
    FUNCTION get_const(p_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END Package1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Package1 IS
  FUNCTION get_const(p_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF p_id = 1 THEN
      RETURN package1.a_constant;
    ELSIF p_id = 2 THEN
      RETURN package1.b_constant;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
END Package1;

SQL> select package1.a_constant from dual;

select package1.a_constant from dual

ORA-06553: PLS-221: 'A_CONSTANT' is not a procedure or is undefined

SQL> select package1.get_const(1) from dual;

PACKAGE1.GET_CONST(1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant value a

SQL>
```

EDIT: If you can't modify these packages, can you create new functions or packages? If you can, you can workaround the issue thusly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_const(p_id NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
BEGIN
  IF p_id = 1 THEN
    RETURN package1.a_constant;
  ELSIF p_id = 2 THEN
    RETURN package1.b_constant;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
/


SQL> select get_const(1) from dual;

GET_CONST(1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant value a

SQL> select get_const(2) from dual;

GET_CONST(2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant value b

SQL>
```

You are allowed to reference public variables from other PL/SQL objects.

In response to your last comment, I've added some code to show how one might write a function to get different values from the package with a single function. If this won't do, I'm afraid you're up the proverbial creek.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately I can't modify these packages :(

Comment: Can you create new pl/sql objects?

Comment: Preferibly not. And if I can, there must be a little set of procedures, not a procedure for every constant. Thanks again.

Comment: You can do it with one function or many - that's up to you, but you will need at least one to get at those constants via SQL. See my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getConstant(p_constant string) return string is
v_val string(100);
begin
    execute immediate 'begin :a :='||p_constant||'; end;' using in out v_val;
    return v_val;
end;
```

And then you can

```
Select getConstant('MyPkg.myConstant') from dual;
```